# Events not detected when using NDSolve with WhenEvents.

Tags: numerical-integration

```
ir1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= .5, {x, y}];
ir2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];

mf1 = RegionMember[ir1];
mf2 = RegionMember[ir2];
solve[r_?NumericQ] :=   
      NDSolveValue[{{x'[t] == vx[t], y'[t] == vy[t]}, 
                   WhenEvent[Or @@ {mf1@{x[t], y[t]}, ! mf2@{x[t], y[t]}},
                             {vy[t] -> -.9  vy[t], vx[t] -> -vx[t]}], 
                   x[0] == 0.6, y[0] == .6, vx[0] == 1, vy[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
                   DiscreteVariables -> {vx, vy}];
sol1 = solve[5];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[1 ;; 2]]}, {t, 0, τ}, 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 1, 
    Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], 
    Epilog -> {ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + y^2 == .5}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}][[1]], Red, 
              PointSize[.05], {Red, Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]] /. (t -> τ), 
              Yellow, Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]] /. (t -> τ), Pink, Thick, 
              Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}}] /. (t -> τ)}}] &@sol1, 
 {{τ, 0.01}, 0.01,  30, .1},  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

#### Question 1

---

Part solution is add option 'AccuracyGoal->inf'
and then this occurs randomly.

When $\color{Green}{t>7.5 \text{ or}\backslash  t=8.41}$, the point will run through the small circle without collision.

[image]

The animation is expected within $\color{Green}{t<7.5}$

#### Question2

---

When $\color{red}{t}$ is greater than $\color{red}{40}$ in `solve`,

### Error Information: [Just Warning Messages could be ignored?]

---

NDSolveValue::evcvmit: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations between t = 30.44217201180905 and t = 33.08872313256998. >>

NDSolveValue::evcvmit: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations between t = 32.11644418013707 and t = 34.79513403482258. >>

NDSolveValue::evcvmit: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations between t = 33.79298201003498 and t = 36.443077010966306. >>

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't get the code to run due to a few errors... However, your solve function is only defined from (0,30). Anything beyond that will cause extrapolation which may be the root of your problem. You should increase t and try again.

Comment: @tarhawk hi, this works only after v 10.0, and you can change (0,30) into (0,40) in the NDSolve

Comment: Despite warning messages, `NDSolveValue::evcvmit: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision ...`, the code produces the desired results for me at least out to `t = 50`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey hi, yes, I read it wrong in my first trying, this is something warning messages. so I edited my question.

Comment: Maybe turn off the annoying message with `Off[NDSolveValue::evcvmit]`.  Is your question answered now?

Comment: @bbgodfrey hi, question1 occurs randomly?

Comment: Both answer below work fine.  Still another would be to use "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation" with `mf1@{x[t], y[t]} mf2@{x[t], y[t]} > 0`, patterned after the answer by @belisarius.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I don't mean to be rude, but the OP should be aware that 2012rcampion's answer don't consider the speed loss.

Comment: @belisarius  The only velocity changes occur during the `WhenEvent`, which has already been triggered by `"LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"`, so I would not expect that velocity change to matter to the linear interpolation.  In any event, no offense taken.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work. However, expect some issues when the trajectory gets almost tangent to the inner circle.

```
mf1[{x_, y_}] := x^2 + y^2 - (1/2)^2
mf2[{x_, y_}] := x^2 + y^2 - 1
sol = NDSolve[{
   x'[t] == vx[t], y'[t] == vy[t],
   WhenEvent[ mf1[{x[t], y[t]}] mf2[{x[t], y[t]}] == 0,
                 {vy[t] -> -9/10 vy[t], vx[t] -> -vx[t]}, "IntegrateEvent" -> True],
   x[0] == 6/10, y[0] == 6/10, vx[0] == 1, vy[0] == 1},
  {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, DiscreteVariables -> {vx, vy}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 25]

Plot[{x[t], y[t], Norm[{x[t], y[t]}]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 40}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}, Evaluated -> True]
Show[ContourPlot[{mf2[{x, y}] == 0, mf1[{x, y}] == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
    ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 40}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: how about the case `, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 50`?

Comment: @HyperGroups If you want to know why increasing the precision get wrong answers I suggest posting another question (search the site before posting!). That's a completely different issue! I think my answer is currently doing what you wanted :)

Comment: @HyperGroups Setting `WorkingPrecision` or `PrecisionGoal` is unnecessary.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I strongly disagree. At least in v9 [it is necessary](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I37Mc.png)

Comment: Maybe the version does matter.  Runs fine for me with 10.0.2.0 in Windows 8.1 (64x) with neither variable set.  In any case, nice Answer above.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks! Mismatching version behavior has been a source of much confusion on the site lately. I think I'll start my answers with a heading line warning about that. Thanks for checking the code.

Answer (score 3):

I found that setting `"LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"` solves the problem by avoiding using a root-finding method to locate the event.  It will also be a little faster, and since your motion is constant speed you will not lose any precision.  (The hint was that the location always failed around `t = 30`, regardless of initial speed or position.)

Also, you can use `MaxStepSize` to avoid skipping over any events.

```
r1[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 < 1/2;
r2[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 > 1;

soln = NDSolve[{
    x''[t] == 0.,
    y''[t] == 0., 
    x[0] == 0.6, 
    y[0] == 0.61,
    x'[0] == 0.02,
    y'[0] == 0.1,
    WhenEvent[Evaluate[r1[x[t], y[t]] || r2[x[t], y[t]]], 
        Evaluate[{x'[t], y'[t]} -> 
            ComplexExpand[ReflectionMatrix[{x[t], y[t]}].{x'[t], y'[t]}]], 
        "LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"]
    }, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1]

Animate[Show[
    RegionPlot[
        Evaluate@{r1[x, y], r2[x, y]},
        {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, 
        PlotRangePadding -> None], 
    ParametricPlot[{x[\[Tau]], y[\[Tau]]} /. soln, {\[Tau], 0, t}, 
        PlotPoints -> 100], 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x[t], y[t]} /. soln]}],
{t, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: I believe the motion isn't "constant speed" as formulated in the question

Comment: @belisarius I think so, since the speeds `vx` and `vy` are unchanged outside of the `WhenEvent`.  Maybe I should have said, "constant speed in between events."

Comment: OK, it doesn't matter too much. Mine was just an observation to bring the attention of the OP to the `ReflectionMatrix[]` transformation so he could decide what kind of change he decides to introduce. Thanks for the kind reply.