# WhenEvent detects only the first event

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

My code is based on the suggestion in [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75729/events-not-detected-when-using-ndsolve-with-whenevents) by Michael E2
And when I'm using the same definitions the `WhenEvent` function locates only the first time the event occurs.

```
slopeα = 0.01; Tend = 10; L = 1;
us[m_, P_] := (1 + Tanh[m (P)])/2;
α1 = 1; α2 = 8; elementNum = 25; ΔPsnap = 0.25;
maxval[if_: InterpolatingFunction[___][x_]] := Max[if /. {x -> "ValuesOnGrid"}];
fnew[if : InterpolatingFunction[___][x_]] := ConstantArray[1, Length[if /. x -> "Grid"]]; 
opts = Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
                  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid",
                                              "MinPoints" -> (elementNum - 1)}};
Pup = 0.7; t0 = 1;
α1 = 1; α2 = 8;
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[P[x, t], t] - α[x, t] D[P[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0, P[x, 0] == 0,
                P[0, t] == UnitStep[t - t0], P[L, t] == 0, α[x, 0] == α2,
                D[α[x, t], t] == 0, WhenEvent[maxval[P[x, t]] >= Pup, Print[t]]},
               {P[x, t], α[x, t]}, {t, 0, Tend}, {x, 0, L}, opts];
Manipulate[Plot[{P[x, t] /. sol1} /. {t -> tt}, {x, 0, L},
           PlotRange -> {{0, L}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> Medium], {tt, 0, Tend}]
```

and the print output is `2.20493` although the value of $P[x,t]$ remains higher than $Pup$ for at all times.

Can't find the reason for this issue.
Thanks a lot,
Ofek.

Comment: WhenEvent only detects the change from `False->True`of the condition !

Comment: Oh, I'm surprised I've missed that, Thanks!!
Maybe you know a way to "force" WhenEvent to check every step?

Comment: The WhenEvent in your simulation doesn't affect NDSolve, so you could check the conditions after the simulation is completed!?

Comment: I have excluded the part that this effect takes place since its too long and maybe have some errors itself, so, unfortunately, that's now the case.

Comment: If I understand your problem right  the ode "changes" when the event occurs? If so you could define a `DiscreteVariable ->switch` and switch between the different ode's.

Comment: It seems like a good idea, I'll take a look at switch function. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, now I understand what you said.
The real thing I want to do is to change a coefficient value for every step in which the pressure surpasses the Pup value, I'm not sure the Switch function will enable this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple realization switching the coefficient of an ode:

```
{X, S} = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + s[t] x[t] == 0, s[0] == 1, x[0] == 0,x'[0] == 1, WhenEvent[x[t] > 0.5, s[t] -> 2],WhenEvent[x[t] < 0.5, s[t] -> 1]}, {x, s}, {t, 0, 10},DiscreteVariables -> s];

{X, S} = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + s[t] x[t] == 0, s'[t] == 0, s[0] == 1,x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, WhenEvent[x[t] > 0.5, s[t] -> 2], WhenEvent[x[t] < 0.5, s[t] -> 1]}, {x, s}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

In both variants you need two WhenEvents!

```
Plot[{X[t], S[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps solving your problem!